# lectura de los dos primeros caracteres

Tags: c#

Estoy tomando la lectura de un scaner en un textbox pero necesito hacer una función que sólo permita los escaneos que comiencen con "3S", de lo contrario me diga error. 
Utilizo este método el cual sólo lo declaro dentro del evento `TextChanged` del **textbox1** en este caso.
**string a** y **string b** son este caso "*3S*" y "*3s*", con los cuales determino que con ellos deben empezar el texto.
Toma la lectura pero me esta quitando el "*3S*", necesito toda la lectura.

```
private void opcion1(TextBox txt)
{   
   string s = txt.Text;
   string a = Properties.Settings.Default.op11;
   string b = Properties.Settings.Default.op12;

   if(s != "")
   {     
      if(s.Length >= 2)
      {
         if (s.startswith(a) || s.startswith(b))  
         {

            if (s.Length > 2)             
            {         
            }
            else
            {
                 s = "";
            }
            txt.Text = s;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Al igual te ayuda un método que se llama **contains** para revisar las letras por pocision del string y así creas tus condiciones. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Si quieres toda la lectura, para que haces `s = "";`?

Comment: Porqué pasas como parámetro todo el TextBox? ¿qué tal si ese método lo quieres reutilizar en otra parte con algún string? cambia el parámetro a string y cuando lo llames, en vez de pasar el TextBox pasas su propiedad Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo modificaría tu método para devolver un `bool` si se produce la regla de negocio que indicas. También evitaría pasar un `TextBox` como parámetro ya que eso hace que modifiques el valor de su propiedad `Text` al ser un objeto que se pasa como referencia a tu método.

```
private bool opcion1(string txt)
{
    bool resultado = false;
    string a = Properties.Settings.Default.op11;
    string b = Properties.Settings.Default.op12;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt))
    {
        if (txt.Length >= 2)
        {
            if (txt.StartsWith(a) || txt.StartsWith(b))
            {
                resultado = true; // dejaremos pasar
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Como hago el llamado a este método en el textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Asi es como tengo el codigo y me funciona bien porque extraigo "3S" cuando lleva este mismo, el detalle es que lee otros valores que no lleven "3S", debo aplicar una condicion que si es diferente de "3S" limpie el campo.

```
Private void opcion1(string txt) 

string s = txt.Text;
        string a = "3S";
        string b = "3s";

        if (s != "")
        {
            if (s.Length >= 2)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith(a) || s.StartsWith(b))
                {
                    if (s.Length > 2)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(s.Length.ToString());
                        s = s.Substring(2);
                    }
                    else
                        s = "";
                }

                txt.Text = s;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ronald, juraría que el problema lo tienes al asignar `s= ""` y luego dejarlo de nuevo en `txt.Texto`.
Cuando `s` empieza con `a` o `b` su longitud es `2` y por tanto vacías la cadena y la devuelves a `txt`.

Comment: Que solución me sugieres aplicar al código que ya tengo realizado?

Comment: Algo parecido a esto, te vaciaría txt si no tienes valor válido:
<!-- language: c# -->
private void opcion1(TextBox txt)
{   
    string s = txt.Text;
    string a = Properties.Settings.Default.op11;
    string b = Properties.Settings.Default.op12;

    if(s != "")
    {     
        if(s.Length >= 2)
        {
            if !(s.startswith(a) || s.startswith(b))  
            {
                s = "";
            }
            txt.Text = s;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Solo me lee los que traen "3S", otro codigo diferente no me lo lee en el textbox. Siempre debe leerlo traiga o no traiga "3S", una vez analizado dira "numero incorrecto".